# Jenkins - Change subject in email-ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I am using email-ext plugin to trigger emails after the build fails or become unstable. The build becomes unstable when some of the tests fail and the build fails when the compilation fail.

Can we use conditions to display different customized subject depending on the cause of the email trigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, below the *Editable email notification* interface there should be an **Advanced settings..** button which will give you access to various triggers. As you add & configure the triggers, you'll note an **Advanced..** button for each of them, which will allow you to fully customize the e-mail template.

[image: Mail configs]